# error: Column `article_content` cannot be named the same as its table

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

I am using this command to generate model using `diesel_ext`:

```
diesel_ext --schema-file src/model/diesel/dolphin/dolphin_schema.rs --model
```

When I using `cargo build` to compile the project. It shows an error like this:

```
error: Column `article_content` cannot be named the same as its table.
 You may use `#[sql_name = "article_content"]` to reference the table's `article_content` column.
 See the documentation of the `table!` macro for details`

  --> src/model/diesel/dolphin/dolphin_schema.rs:37:1
   |
37 | / table! {
38 | |     article_content (id) {
39 | |         id -> Int8,
40 | |         article_id -> Int8,
41 | |         article_content -> Varchar,
42 | |     }
43 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `__static_cond` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: could not compile `reddwarf-admin` due to previous error
```

What should I do to config to add the `#[sql_name = "article_content"]` comment before the column? I could not found any tips from the document. I tried to add comment like this:

```
table! {
    article_content (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        article_id -> Int8,
        #[sql_name = "article_content"]
        article_content -> Varchar,
    }
}
```

still did not fix this problem. More import, I was wonder is it possible to make diesel support with the table column name could be the same with the table name, so that I did not change anything. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweak the code like this would fixed this problem:

```
table! {
    article_content (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        article_id -> Int8,
        #[sql_name = "article_content"]
        articleContent -> Varchar,
    }
}
```

It will map the colum `articleContent` to database `article_content`. I have to tweak this code every time after using script auto generate, that's the difficult way to tweak every time.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example here in the documentation of the [`table!`](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/macro.table.html#example-usage) macro.